# Running Karate API tests using standalone CLI

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, karate

We are using Karate within VS Code using the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate) on Windows

The documentation for the [Parallel Execution](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution) states that it can run **standalone** without Maven, Gradle or JUnit

> Karate can run tests in parallel, and dramatically cut down execution time. This is a 'core' feature and does not depend on JUnit, Maven or Gradle.

But the documentation for the [Command Line](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#command-line) and [Debug Server](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Debug-Server#karate-cli) shows examples for running with Maven command (`mvn test`) and Gradle (`./gradlew test`), but I cannot see an entry point for a standalone Karate CLI...

Is there a way to run the Karate CLI on Windows with only the VS Code extension installed?

If not, then what *does* the Karate CLI depend on? Do I need to have the JDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

The VS Code extension is great for getting teams started. You can [run tests in parallel using the extension](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension#launch-configurations) if you upgrade to the pro version. Yes, the plugin embeds Karate and a JRE and it is not designed for "batch" use.

So for scaling to a team or the typical CI pipeline, you should probably use the standalone-JAR (and install a JRE): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/wiki/Run-Mode:-Custom

Note that it is very easy to embed the executable into a Docker container: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Other-Runtime-Options